# Existence of function satisfying some properties.

Tags: analysis, functions

Is there  continuous function $f(x)$ satisfy
$$
0\le f \le M_1 \\
\int_{\mathbb R^n} |z|^2 f(z) dz \le M_2   \\
\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(z) dz = (M_1B_n)^{2/(n+2)} M_2^{n/(n+2)}~(\frac{n+2}{n})^{n/(n+2)}
$$
where $B_n$ is the volume of the unit ball of $\mathbb R^n$.

This problem origins from the Lemma 1 of

*Li, Peter; Yau, Shing-Tung*, [**On the Schrödinger equation and the eigenvalue problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01213210), Commun. Math. Phys. 88, 309-318 (1983). [ZBL0554.35029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0554.35029).

I don't know whether the inequation in Lemma 1 is sharp, so I ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=1$,  let
\begin{align}
&f(x)=M_1,~~~|x|\le \left(\frac{3M_2}{2M_1}\right)^{1/3}=T  \\
&f(x)=0,~~~~~~~\text{others}
\end{align}
therefore, we have
$$
0\le f\le M_1 \\
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2 f(x) dx = 
\int_{-T }^{+T} 
x^2 M_1 dx
=\frac{2M_1}{3}T^3
=M_2
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx
=
\int_{-T }^{+T} M_1 dx
=
2M_1 \left(\frac{3M_2}{2M_1}\right)^{1/3}
$$
note that, when $n=1$, we have
$$
2M_1 \left(\frac{3M_2}{2M_1}\right)^{1/3}
=
(M_1B_n)^{2/(n+2)} M_2^{n/(n+2)}~(\frac{n+2}{n})^{n/(n+2)}
$$